# How do you create Azure VM from image with unmanaged disk?

Tags: azure, azure-networking

I have a Datacenter 2016 server with unmanaged disk. I need to be able to replicate this VM and continue using an unmanaged disk.

Do I need to provision the VM i want to replicate? Or can I just use the VHD in storage to create a new VM?

Here is my powershell script so far. Note that I tried to provision a VM

```
New-AzVm `
    -ResourceGroupName "myResource" `
    -Name "myVM" `
    -ImageName "" ` //IS THIS WHERE YOU WOULD PUT A VHD? 
    -Location "West US 2" `
    -VirtualNetworkName "my-vnet" `
    -SubnetName "default" `
    -SecurityGroupName "myvmNSG" `
    -OpenPorts 3389, 80, 443
```

Comment: Do you want to use an unmanaged disk for the new VM too, or can it have use a managed disk?

Comment: It needs to be unmanaged. Can I use the vhd?

Comment: There is a surprising lack of documentation about using unmanaged disk nowadays, but yes. Unfortunately I don't have a script at hand at the moment, but you should be able to do so with the same syntax that was widely used before managed disk became predominant. Now, if only I could still find an example somewhere...

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to use unmanaged disks? They are a lot more difficult to manage (heh) than managed ones...

Answer (score 1):

Found it!

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sa-create-vm-specialized

The most important part:

```
$osDiskUri = "https://myStorageAccount.blob.core.windows.net/myContainer/myOsDisk.vhd"
```

Basically, you need to reference the blob storage where the VHD resides using its URI; have a look at the page for the complete script.

Of course, ***you can't attach the existing disk to a new VM***; you need to make a copy of it. And, since it's unmanaged, this means you'll need to perform a blob copy between storage accounts. This should help:

https://docs.microsoft.com/it-it/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs
https://docs.microsoft.com/it-it/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-blobs#copy-blobs-between-storage-accounts